# Push UIView after Modal

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a modal transition to move between view1 to view2 and i want to use pop transition (programmatically) from view2 to view3, but it doesn't work (I am using navigation controller as root):

the code is (in view2):

```
    view3 *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view3"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

how should the code be?

Comment: Which view you want to pop? means view1, view2 or view3?

Comment: Provide more code how to transit from view1 to view2 would help us understand better.

Comment: @Unheilig 
the storyboard is like this: navigation_controller as root, view1 connected to view2 by modal transition (non-programatly, via storyboard. view2 connected to view3 by push transition (like the code i wrote up). 
when i click on the button nothing happens, i wrote NSSlog in the button action to verify its ok (it is :)).
i read somewhere that the problem could be due to stack issues. right?

Answer (score 0):

All looks good to me in terms of code.

You should provide information about why this is not working... Are you getting an error? IF so where?

How do you initate the push to the new controller? Try using NSLog(@"Hello"); to make sure that this is being called correctly.

Further to this, the issue could be that the storyboard is not being returned with self.storyboard. You can always try

```
UIStoryboard *appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME_HERE" bundle:nil];
```

Then use

```
view3 *controller = [appStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view3"];
```

Comment: there is no error, nothing happened, view3 not loading. if i use Push not programmatically but through the storyboard, the simulator crash.

Comment: It seems a pretty simple setup there is not much to get wrong here. You should provide more information, code, pictures of storyboard in your question